# RabbitMq refuses connection when run in docker

Tags: sockets, rabbitmq, .net-core, docker-compose

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  explore:
    image: explore
    build:
      context: ./Explore
      dockerfile: VsDockerfile
    environment:
      - "ElasticUrl=http://localhost:9200"
      - "RabbitMq/Host=localhost"
      - "RabbitMq/Username=guest"
      - "RabbitMq/Password=guest"
    networks:
      - localnet

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - localnet

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6.7-management
    hostname: rabbit
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - localnet

networks:
  localnet:
    external:
      name: localnet
```

If I type http://localhost:15672 in the browser, I get the rabbitmq interface, but if I tries to connect from my Explore project like this:

```
public SqlToRabbitProcessor(SqlToRabbitRepository sqlToRabbitRepository)
{
    _sqlToRabbitRepository = sqlToRabbitRepository;

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        HostName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RabbitMq/Host"),
        UserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RabbitMq/Username"),
        Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RabbitMq/Password")
    };

    var rabbit = factory.CreateConnection();
    channel = rabbit.CreateModel();
}
```

Then it breaks in the line

```
var rabbit = factory.CreateConnection();
```

with the error saying

ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne(IEndpointResolver resolver, Func selector)

BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, string clientProvidedName)

Comment: Hmm I think the issue is that in my web container I call localhost, and that's not the Hosts localhost but the containers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As my comment under the question suggested, it's because the "localhost" defined in the web application part is it's containers localhost, and not the docker host..

just needed to change

```
- "ElasticUrl=http://localhost:9200"
- "RabbitMq/Host=localhost"
```

to

```
- "ElasticUrl=http://elasticsearch:9200"
- "RabbitMq/Host=rabbit"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with docker-compose.

I solved it by with hostname:

```
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    command: sh -c "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management; rabbitmq-server"
    image: rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: admin
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: admin
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions on this [post](https://github.com/pbushan/resolute-hub.git).

Just to benefit people that stumble upon this question. The --link feature is now considered legacy and is a prime candidate to be deprecated by docker.
The easiest way is to use

> depends_on:
>   In order to do this, its recommended to first create a network like so"

```
docker network create <network_name>
```

Then use `docker-compose up` to spawn services that bind with each other. Look at the example below where I've bound my spring-boot app to rabbit-mq. You can clone my repo from [here](https://github.com/pbushan/resolute-hub.git)

```html
version: "3.1"
services:
  rabbitmq-container:
    image: rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq-container
    ports:
      - 5673:5673
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - resolute

  resolute-container:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - spring_rabbitmq_host=rabbitmq-container
      - spring_rabbitmq_port=5672
      - spring_rabbitmq_username=guest
      - spring_rabbitmq_password=guest
      - resolute_rabbitmq_publishQueueName=resolute-run-request
      - resolute_rabbitmq_exchange=resolute
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq-container
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - resolute

networks:
  resolute:
    external:
      name: resolute
```

See how I've created a network called `resolute` and bound the apps to the same network. I've also given my rabbitmq-container a `hostname`. This is because docker now prepends the container name and that makes it difficult to bind services by name.